# Is it a bug or a feature? In some cases it is possible to access the UI thread from a task not running on the UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading

The developer.android.com says:

> Only objects running on the UI thread have access to other objects on
>   that thread.

That said, all the following examples (cases A..C) should not work since they try to modify an object in the UI thread. But in fact cases A and B do access the object (TextView) in the UI thread.

*Here we start a new thread from the MainActivity:*

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}
```

*Case A (the object in the UI thread is modified)*

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        final TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        myTextView.setText("Hello there!");
    }
}
```

*Case B (the object in the UI thread is modified multiple times)*

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        final TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        for (int i=0; i < 600; i++) {
            myTextView.setText("Hello there!");
        }
    }
}
```

*Case C (after a slight delay the object in the UI thread is not modified)*

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        final TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        try {Thread.sleep(900);} catch (InterruptedException e) {};
        myTextView.setText("Hello there!");
    }
}
```

*Only the case C throws the exception:*

> CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created
>   a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Am I missing something? At the moment it seems that in some cases the UI thread can be modified from a thread not running on the UI thread (if it happens fast enough).

Comment: where did you test it?

Comment: Your code is probably running before the UI is shown.

Comment: Android SDK 16. The code works for both real device and emulator. Should I mention this in the original post to make it more clear? @Blackbelt

Comment: not really, I was just curious

Comment: I believe it is true. The ambiguity is caused by the strict formulation, precisely the word "access". In fact it is possible to access objects in the UI thread despite the guide saying otherwise. This bug|feature is of limited use, but still. @SLaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is some kind of fun. You cannot **update the UI** in background thread. But in this case, UI is not drawn yet so it doesn't treat your code like **update** the UI but more like **set** the value. Anyway if you update it after the UI was shown, it will be treated like **UI updating**.

Comment: I believe it is true. The exception is thrown for all the A..C cases if we try to override, say, onResume method instead of onCreate. The ambiguity is caused by the strict formulation, precisely the word "access". It should say something like "update" or "modify" (as opposed to "set") since it is possible to access objects in the UI thread despite the guide saying otherwise. This bug|feature is of limited use, but still.